# jquery ui autocomplete custom data syntax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a web app which uses the jquery ui autocomplete plugin.

JS:

```
<script>
$(function() {$( ".autocomplete-2" ).autocomplete({delay: 0, source: window.players, minLength: 2, autoFocus: true});});
</script>
```

I use a basic array to supply names to the jQ ui plugin:

```
var players = 
[
"Addabbo, Eric", 
"Addison, Jackson",
"Callea, Thomas"
]
```

But I **already** have this data in another larger file:
as documented at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data but I don't understand how to use "var members" like the demo uses "var projects". Could somebody please help with the correct syntax?

```
var members = [
{
"Name": "Adeyemon, Murie",
"Rating": 1000,
"USCF_Exp": "2009-10-10",
"ID": 16720664
},
{
"Name": "Ahmed, Jamshed",
"Rating": 1735,
"USCF_Exp": "2019-10-10",
"ID": 12537964
},
{
"Name": "Attaya, James",
"Rating": 1535,
"USCF_Exp": "2018-10-10",
"ID": 12210580
}

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding jQuery to Your Web Page :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

your script :

```
 <script>
  $( function() {
    var members = [
{
"Name": "Adeyemon, Murie",
"Rating": 1000,
"USCF_Exp": "2009-10-10",
"ID": 16720664
},
{
"Name": "Ahmed, Jamshed",
"Rating": 1735,
"USCF_Exp": "2019-10-10",
"ID": 12537964
},
{
"Name": "Attaya, James",
"Rating": 1535,
"USCF_Exp": "2018-10-10",
"ID": 12210580
}

];

    $( "#member" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: members ,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#member" ).val( ui.item.Name);
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#member" ).val( ui.item.Name);
        $( "#member-Rating" ).val( ui.item.Rating);
        $( "#member-USCF_Exp" ).html( ui.item.USCF_Exp);
        $( "#member-id" ).html( ui.item.ID);


        return false;
      }
    })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<div>" + item.Name+ "<br>" + item.Rating+ "</div>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  } );
  </script>
```

your code html :

```
<input id="member">
<input type="hidden" id="member-id">
<p id="member-USCF_Exp"></p>
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. Any chance you could take out the extra code...?

Comment: Of course. But can you get rid of the extra code. I don't care about <input id = "member"> Just help me understand this. I need this.

Comment: you have tell me : "Just help me understand this" . you can precise your question ?  you want understand about this code : 
-------
 $( "#member" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: members ,      focus: function( event, ui ) { ..

Comment: I want the excess verbiage removed. I just want the autocomplete to work with the data file. I don't care about <input id="member">
<input type="hidden" id="member-id"> <p id="member-USCF_Exp"></p> I don't care about $( "#member-USCF_Exp" ).html( ui.item.USCF_Exp); and the other things not relevant to the core syntax.